# Symfony 4.4 - Problem to add in database with relation many to many

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a little problem with the many-to-many relationship. I have a user class, and a skill class (competence), I linked it both with a many-to-many relationship, so that gives me the skill_user (competence_user) table. the problem is that I cannot add data to this table via a form.. Thanks for your help..

ps: i have this error:

Neither the property "competences" nor one of the methods "getCompetences()", "competences()", "isCompetences()", "hasCompetences()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\Competence".

the Competence class :

`<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CompetenceRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CompetenceRepository::class)
 */
class Competence
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="competences")
     */
    private $apprenant;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->apprenant = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getApprenant(): Collection
    {
        return $this->apprenant;
    }

    public function addApprenant(User $apprenant): self
    {
        if (!$this->apprenant->contains($apprenant)) {
            $this->apprenant[] = $apprenant;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeApprenant(User $apprenant): self
    {
        $this->apprenant->removeElement($apprenant);

        return $this;
    }
}`

the User class :

`` <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 * fields= {"email"},
 * message= "L'email que vous avez indiquez est déjà utilisé")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath = "password", message="Votre mot de passe doit être identique à celui entré au dessus")
     */
    public $confirm_password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $adresse;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $CP;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Ville;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $tel;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $portfolio;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $github;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $CV;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $promotion;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $avatar;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $mobile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $mobileZone;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Candidature::class, mappedBy="apprenant")
     */
    private $candidatures;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Competence::class, mappedBy="apprenant")
     */
    private $competences;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->candidatures = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->competences = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adresse;
    }

    public function setAdresse(string $adresse): self
    {
        $this->adresse = $adresse;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCP(): ?string
    {
        return $this->CP;
    }

    public function setCP(string $CP): self
    {
        $this->CP = $CP;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVille(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Ville;
    }

    public function setVille(string $Ville): self
    {
        $this->Ville = $Ville;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->tel;
    }

    public function setTel(string $tel): self
    {
        $this->tel = $tel;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPortfolio(): ?string
    {
        return $this->portfolio;
    }

    public function setPortfolio(string $portfolio): self
    {
        $this->portfolio = $portfolio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGithub(): ?string
    {
        return $this->github;
    }

    public function setGithub(string $github): self
    {
        $this->github = $github;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCV(): ?string
    {
        return $this->CV;
    }

    public function setCV(string $CV): self
    {
        $this->CV = $CV;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPromotion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->promotion;
    }

    public function setPromotion(string $promotion): self
    {
        $this->promotion = $promotion;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAvatar(): ?string
    {
        return $this->avatar;
    }

    public function setAvatar(string $avatar): self
    {
        $this->avatar = $avatar;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMobile(): ?int
    {
        return $this->mobile;
    }

    public function setMobile(int $mobile): self
    {
        $this->mobile = $mobile;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMobileZone(): ?int
    {
        return $this->mobileZone;
    }

    public function setMobileZone(int $mobileZone): self
    {
        $this->mobileZone = $mobileZone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Candidature[]
     */
    public function getCandidatures(): Collection
    {
        return $this->candidatures;
    }

    public function addCandidature(Candidature $candidature): self
    {
        if (!$this->candidatures->contains($candidature)) {
            $this->candidatures[] = $candidature;
            $candidature->setApprenant($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCandidature(Candidature $candidature): self
    {
        if ($this->candidatures->removeElement($candidature)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($candidature->getApprenant() === $this) {
                $candidature->setApprenant(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Competence[]
     */
    public function getCompetences(): Collection
    {
        return $this->competences;
    }

    public function addCompetence(Competence $competence): self
    {
        if (!$this->competences->contains($competence)) {
            $this->competences[] = $competence;
            $competence->addApprenant($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCompetence(Competence $competence): self
    {
        if ($this->competences->removeElement($competence)) {
            $competence->removeApprenant($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }


    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        
    }
    public function getSalt()
    {
        
    }
} ``

the form :

`<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Competence;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UserCompetenceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('competences')
        ->add('apprenant')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Competence::class,
        ]);
    }
}`

Comment: The error message is about as clear as it can be - the class `Competence` doesn't have a property `competences` which you try to add in the builder. If you're basing a form on an entity, then you need to either add only the properties that it actually has or define custom behaviour for those it doesn't.

Comment: What exactly do you want to edit? Why is that entity named `UserCompetenceType`, but uses the `data_class` `Competence`?

Comment: @NicoHaase I want each user to be able to add skills to their profile

Comment: @El_Vanja Ok thank you, but in this case it is the command lines that I entered in the cli that made this form, it's weird isn't it?

Comment: If automation created this, yes, it would be weird. I've never used CLI for form creation, which command did you use?

Comment: @El_Vanja php bin/console make:form

Comment: I see that this command only builds a skeleton of the `FormType`. You can still manually edit it to add/remove what you need in the form. So feel free to play around, comment out the troubling field and add whatever needs to be there.

Comment: @El_Vanja okay i'll try, thank you =)

Answer (score -1):

To be more specific let's say you have entity `User` and inside your `User` entity you have different properties such as `title, description` you name it. So in `builder->add` you can specify only properties from your `User` entity:

```
builder->add('title')
builder->add('description')
```

Comment: Please share more details. How do these two lines resolve the given error message? Keep in mind that a good explanation helps others to learn from your answer